# Rails 3 HABTM not changing created_at and updated_at fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models: Product and Categories. They have a HABTM relationship.

At products form i have:

```
<% Category.find(:all).each do |c| %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'product[category_ids][]', c.id, @product.category_ids.include?(c.id) %> <%=c.name%>
<% end %>
```

It works perfectly but when a categories_products record is created, the created_at field is empty ( 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ).

How can i make Rails create/update those fields?

Thanks.